# how to use = assignment operator with timestamp date column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using timestamp in dat column in table r3. when I fire command

```
select dat from r3 where dat='16-nov-09';
```

it shows "no rows selected" but when i fire command

```
select dat from r3 where dat>'15-nov-09';
```

it shows the whole data of 16-nov-09. Tell me what is wrong in my first command or what i have to do.

Comment: use to_date while in your where condition.

Comment: Dont shout. Use mixed case when asking you question and format it.

Comment: Sorry @zendar, seems our edits overlapped (but were mostly the same ;-))

Answer (score 6):

Quering on oracle date columns is always confusing. The date columntype is always a datetime. Storing the current date from sysdate stores always the time component too.

There good and evil ways quering the date columns. I show and vote some.

```
where to_char(DAT, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = '16-NOV-2009'

where trunc(DAT) = to_date('16-NOV-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Both bad, because they do not use any index. To avoid this, you can define a function based index on the expression.
The trick of both is to cut off the time component. If time is not needed, than it is a good advise to cut off the time in INSERT and UPDATE trigger. The function based index can convert to a normal index.

```
where DAT between to_date('16-NOV-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
          and to_date('16-NOV-2009 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

where DAT >= to_date('16-NOV-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY') and DAT < to_date('16-NOV-2009', 'DD-MON-YYYY')+1
```

This two are always my favorites. 
Its a good advice to use to_date and to_char to convert the values between string and datetime.

Comment: Cut off the time with a trigger?  The last thing I would do is use a trigger to "massage" the data. However I do agree with your solution.

Comment: I really like the 'where to_char(DAT, ''DD-MON-YYYY') = '16-NOV-2009').  I never thought of converting a date row to that format with that syntax.

Comment: Programs running with different nls language parameters teached me to use format mask always.

Answer (score 2):

As DAT is timestamp you can use as below

```
select DAT from R3 
where DAT between to_date('16-NOV-09' , 'dd-MON-yy') and to_date('16-NOV-09 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp has time and date components, so query

```
select dat from r3 where dat='16-nov-09';
```

will work only for records where time component is midnight: '00:00:00'

Beside formatting (to_date function), you can truncate timestamp to get only date:

```
select dat from r3 where trunc(dat)='16-nov-09';
```

Beware that this will not use index on field `dat` (if there is any).

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP and DATE are different data types in oracle and both store time components. If you really do need to store subsecond times then you use TIMESTAMP, otherwise DATE is your best choice.

The ANSI timestamp and date literal syntaxes are quite handy:

```
create table ts_test (ts1 timestamp);

select *
from   ts_test
where  ts1 > timestamp '2009-10-11 00:00:00'
/

select *
from   ts_test
where  ts1 > timestamp '2009-10-11 00:00:00.1'
/

select *
from   ts_test
where  ts1 > timestamp '2009-10-11 00:00:00.001'
/

select *
from   ts_test
where  ts1 = date '2009-10-11'
/
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below format for a date field in where condition.

```
where to_char(DAT,'mmddyyyy') = '11152009';
```

Comment: I still wonder which imbecile invented Yoda date formatting (mmddyyyy)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle the date fields also contain a time component, so 16-nov-09 is actually midnight of Nov 16th.

Two different ways to handle this:

```
where to_char(DAT,'mmddyyyy') = '11152009'
```

as john suggested, but I like the following version more:

```
where trunc(dat) = to_date ('11152009', 'mmddyyyy')
```

`TRUNC`for a date "removes" the time component (or to be more specific, truncates it to midnight), and to_date is the proper way to construct a date value in Oracle SQL. (I prefer to do the comparisons in the right domain - DATEs as in the second example- over another - STRINGs as in the first example. With strings you may run into some weird month issues, sorting is easier in dates etc.)

Comment: Note that both of these would be unable to use an index on DAT (although they could use an appropriate function-based index if one were created).  Using BETWEEN as suggested by valli would allow a range scan on an index.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to it , An easy way out when you are not bothered about the time-stamp but just want to compare the date is to use the 'like' operator.
for example

```
select dat from r3 where dat LIKE '16-nov-09%'
```

will give you desired output.

Comment: -1: This query will _not_ work (1; Without a trailing wildcard, `LIKE` is equivalent to `=` 2; It also isn't case insensitive 3; If the db is in a different language than English, you might not call it "November" anyways).  It's also going to avoid the use of any/all indices (because of converting/formatting), making it dog-slow on a table of any real size.  And.... this question is over 3 years old, with several viable answers (over which this is not an improvement).

Comment: Sorry missed the wild card ,regarding case insensitivity this is specific to what the questions said to search , ofcourse it wont work for any other db or any other date format either.I found this useful while doing a quick search on a small table where i dont bother about the size of table and I am sure about the date format that i have to search.

Comment: The mixed case is "working" in the question, due to which type is being converted - it's converting the string into a date/timestamp type for comparison to a timestamp column, which is ignoring the case.  Your version is converting the timestamp column to a string, which usually results in uppercase for _at least_ the first character of the month, if not the whole abbreviation.  And that's assuming that the format you're using is the one chosen by the system!  The result format chosen is usually dependent on the locale...